# io.cucumber.java.PendingException: TODO: implement me

Tags: selenium, maven, cucumber, runtime-error, issue-tracking

io.cucumber.java.PendingException: TODO: implement me

The above error message is displaying while I run my test case.
Browser opened and access the specified URL. After that I'm getting this error.
Can someone help.

```
@Given("Access the website")
public void access_the_website() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Users//Jayalekshmi//Desktop//Automation//chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    System.out.println("heloo");
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Given("Click Login option")
public void click_login_option() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.wait();
    System.out.println("Hiiii");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a[1]")).click();
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
```

My browser opened and window maximized and access the URL.
After that I'm getting error.

After accessing the URL, I'm expecting to click on the Login option available on the website.

Comment: it's erroring because you're telling it to error - this line throws the exception: `throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this part:

```
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
```

This is added automatically in case you forget to implement the step definition.